How can I apply TS Conditional types, Mapped Types on this method?
I'm working with a TypeScript class that represents a form with various input types. Each input class has a getValue() method that returns different types based on the input. I need to create a type for the return of the getMetadata() method that accurately reflects these values.
Here's the structure of my classes:
interface Field {
    TypeAsString: 'Text'|'Number'|'Choice'|'MultiChoice'|'Boolean'|'User';
    InternalName: string;
    Choices?: string[];
}

class PickerInput {
    values: { key: number|string, text: string, item?: any}[];
    getValue(){
        return this.values || [];
    }
}

class SwitchInput {
    value: boolean;
    getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}

class TextFieldInput {
    value: string|number;
    getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}

Finally, I have a class that represents the whole form Form and has the property inputs and a method called getMetadata():
class Form {
    inputs: {
        [x: string]: PickerInput | SwitchInput | TextFieldInput;
    };
    params: {
        fields: Field[]
    };

    constructor (params: { fields: Field[] }) {
        this.params = params;

        // Iterate the array of fields and populate the "inputs" object
        for (let f = 0; params.fields.length; f++) {
            let field = params.fields[f];

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Text') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new TextFieldInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Number') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new TextFieldInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Choice') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'MultiChoice') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Boolean') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new SwitchInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'User') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }
        }
    }

    getMetadata(){
        const self = this;
        let metadata = {};

        for (let key in self.inputs){
            let input = self.inputs[key],
                value = input.getValue(),
                field = self.params.fields.find(f => f.InternalName == key) as Field;
            
            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Choice'){
                metadata[field.InternalName] = value[0].key;

            } 
            else if (field.TypeAsString == 'MultiChoice'){
                let results: any[] = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
                    results.push(value[i].key);
                }
                
                metadata[field.InternalName] = {'results': results};
                
            } 
            else if (field.TypeAsString == 'Boolean'){
                metadata[field.InternalName] = value;

            }
            else if (field.TypeAsString == 'User'){
                metadata[field.InternalName + 'Id'] = value[0].key;

            }
            else {
                metadata[field.InternalName] = value;
            }
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}

An example for this should be:
let f: Field[] = [
   { InternalName: 'Name', TypeAsString: 'Text' }, 
   { InternalName: 'Age', TypeAsString: 'Number' }, 
   { InternalName: 'User', TypeAsString: 'User' }, 
   { InternalName: 'IsPerson', TypeAsString: 'Boolean' }, 
   { InternalName: 'Nationality', TypeAsString: 'MultiChoice', Choices: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] }
];

let form = new Form({ fields: f });

Now the type of form.inputs should be:
{
   Name: TextFieldInput;
   Age: TextFieldInput;
   User: PickerInput;
   IsPerson: SwitchInput
   Nationality: PickerInput;
}

And the form.getMetadata() should returns (values are examples):
{
   Name: 'John',
   Age: 30,
   UserId: 10,   // Note the 'Id' at the end of the InternalName. This is valid for User fields
   IsPerson: true,
   Nationality: {
      results: ['A', 'C']
   }
}

I’ve tried using conditional types and mapped types like this:
// Types that should end with 'Id'
enum TypeAsStringId {
    'User' = 'User',
}

// Type that adds 'Id' to the end of the property name if necessary
type MetadataProperty<T> = T extends TypeAsStringId ? `${string & T}Id` : T;

type MetadataValue<T> = T extends { key: infer K }[] ? { results: K[] } :
                        T extends boolean ? boolean :
                        T extends number|string ? T :
                        null;

// Mapped type to apply MetadataValue on MetadataProperty
type MetadataReturnType<T = Form['inputs']> = {
    [P in keyof T as MetadataProperty<P>]: MetadataValue<T[P]>
};

However, I’m unsure if this is the correct approach. How can I improve this type definition to ensure it handles all cases correctly?

Could you [edit] to give a self-contained [mre] suitable for copy-pasting where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about, and they clearly jump out at us? Right now I see lots of errors in the TS playground because, among other things, you're not initializing your class properties. And I'm not sure from this where your problem actually is. I'm loath to wade into this without a starting point that makes sense to me.

First let's define some helpful types to give us shorthands to use elsewhere in the program and to have all the types in one place.
type PickerKey = number | string;
type PickerFieldTypes = {
    type: 'Choice'|'MultiChoice'|'User'
    input: PickerInput
    value: { key: PickerKey, text: string, item?: any}[] // type returned from getValue
    metadata: PickerKey | { results: PickerKey[] } // all types of possible entries into the metadata output from this input type
}
type SwitchFieldTypes = {
    type: 'Boolean'
    input: SwitchInput
    value: boolean
    metadata: boolean
}
type TextFieldTypes = {
    type: 'Text'|'Number'
    input: TextFieldInput
    value: string|number
    metadata: string|number
}
type ValidFields = PickerFieldTypes | SwitchFieldTypes | TextFieldTypes

Next, we want to move more logic into the Input itself. If we export a { key: <expected-metadata-key>, value: <metadata-value> } structure from within a getMetadata(...args): {key, value} function, we can simplify the configuration inside the main code path. Each complicated input can know about its own logic.
class PickerInput {
    values?: PickerFieldTypes['value'];
    getValue() {
        return this.values || [];
    }
    getMetadata(fieldName: string, typeAsString: string): { key: string, value: PickerFieldTypes['metadata'] }  {
      const metadata: MetadataEntry<PickerFieldTypes['metadata']> = {
        key: fieldName,
        value: "", // assign a default value in the case no value was picked
      }
      const picker_value = this.getValue()

      if (typeAsString == 'Choice' && picker_value.length > 0 ) {
        metadata.value = picker_value[0].key
      } else if (typeAsString == 'MultiChoice'){
        metadata.value = {
          results: picker_value.map(val => val.key)
        } 
      } else if (typeAsString == 'User') {
        metadata.key = fieldName + 'Id'
        if (picker_value.length > 0 ) {
          metadata.value = picker_value[0].key
        }
      }
      return metadata
    }
}

And then that leaves our Form
class Form {
    inputs: {
        [x: string]: ValidFields['input'],
    };
    params: {
        fields: Field[]
    };

    constructor (params: { fields: Field[] }) {
        this.params = params;
        this.inputs= {}

        // Iterate the array of fields and populate the "inputs" object
        for (let f = 0; params.fields.length; f++) {
            let field = params.fields[f];

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Text') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new TextFieldInput("");
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Number') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new TextFieldInput(0);
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Choice') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'MultiChoice') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'Boolean') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new SwitchInput();
            }

            if (field.TypeAsString == 'User') {
                this.inputs[field.InternalName] = new PickerInput();
            }
        }
    }

    getMetadata(){
        const self = this;
        let metadata: { [key: string]: ValidFields['metadata'] } = {};

        for (let key in self.inputs){
            let input = self.inputs[key];
            let field = self.params.fields.find(f => f.InternalName == key) as Field;
            
            if ('getMetadata' in input) {
              const {key, value} = input.getMetadata(field.InternalName, field.TypeAsString);
              metadata[key] = value
            } else {
              metadata[field.InternalName] = input.getValue()
            }
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}

playground link
This approach could be optimised further by creating another object to place all the relevant field information (fieldName and valueAsText), rather than having to find the information on each run of getMetadata(). A builder could be written to create the correct field directly off the string passed in as well.
